# Photoshop CS6: Cropping and resizing images simultaneously

Tags: adobe-photoshop, crop

Maybe I've just completely missed the option, but how in the world do you crop and resize an image simultaneously in PS CS6? In CS5 and prior, when using the crop tool, I could set dimensions for the crop, resize the crop area to my liking, and cropping would resize the image - not just change the aspect ratio while maintaining the original image size.

I know that I can go down to "Size & Resolution..." in the dropdown on the left side of the crop toolbar, but that seems more than a little kludgy when previous versions could do it without any fancy footwork.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe this will help:

I crop at `13" x 18"`, and when I put that (exactly as it is) in to the crop tool, it would crop to an aspect ratio of that size but the image would not be `13 inches x 18 inches`.

I finally figured out that I needed to put `13`**`in`** x `18`**`in`** into the crop tool and it worked, it needed to know that it was inches.  Hope this helps.